# VBA Performance: parallel or sequential analysis

Tags: performance, vba, ms-word

I am creating a tool to help analyse revised documents. There are many checks that are performed on hundreds of files, about 10k characters in average.

I have a class for each analysis, and those checks are mostly done on a sentence by sentence basis.

Now, I am wondering if the best approach is to send each document to be analyzed in full by each analyzer, or to loop through sentences or paragraphs and send each to every analyzer.

So the options are

1- Get document, get a sentence, pass it to every analyzer, then move to the next sentence, when it is over, move to next document.

2- Get a document, send it to each analyzer, then move to next document.

I cannot tell which performance factor would impact more:

- Use of paragraph or sentence collection versus string manipulation of the whole file
- If there even is another way to run through a document all at once besides enumerating paragraphs or sentences
- Other performance factors I don't know of.

I hope someone can offer at least a lead on this,

If not I **will** run performance checks on all available options since this task will take a long time to execute (we are talking hours probably) so every improvement counts. And this strategy is certainly one of the major performance bottlenecks. In this case, I will post my results.

Thanks.

Comment: VBA is single-threaded in every environment I am aware of - DO you mean VB.NET or do you know of a multi-threaded VBA environment?

Comment: I mean paralel, not multi-threaded. Send the whole document to each analysis routine or each paragraph to those routines.

Comment: By the way I have seen talks about multi-thread-ish on VBA using windows API, COM or vbscript... Ugly stuff, and it still doesn't make VBA multi-threaded.
Also, I think excel formulas are multi-threaded, so if they call VBA functions I thing they run concurrently. I've seen this behavior on slow formulas but I'm not sure.

Comment: Exactly; calling a multi-threaded DOT NET component from within VBA, using Interop, is feasible but doesn't make VBA multi-threaded. Same goes for calling ADO asynchronously.

Comment: True, but my question is about how to organize my procedure calls, and the performance impact of each option, both of them pure old VBA single threaded.
I cannot develop anywhere but in VBA since that's the only tool available. Plus, I don't want to go multi-threaded.

Comment: Write a profiler and test each option with sample data.

Comment: It's just as likely that the performance will be constrained by exactly how the analysis routines are implemented as by the sequence in which you call them.  Without a lot more detail about what you're doing and an outline proposed architecture, it's impossible to realistically address your question.

Comment: You are all saying that the performance can only be measured once I can run it both ways and clock it. And I don't disagree.

I just thought there could be someone with an idea on whether iterating once through paragraphs, sending it to each class would be faster or if letting each class iterate on its own would (possibly with a different strategy than paragraphs).

I'll find out on my own and post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider this pretty much a no-brainer - do as large of a chunk as you can hold in memory at the same time.

Most of the performance issues in Word come from resolving Ranges and Selections.  Paragraphs, Sentences, and Words are even worse because Word has to pre-parse the content so it knows where they begin and end.

This benchmark should give you a pretty good idea.  The "analysis" is just a busy-work function that works on the text of a Range, and the document was composed of 20 paragraphs of *Lorem Ipsum* retrieved from [www.lipsum.com](http://www.lipsum.com/).

**Benchmark Code:**

```
Private Const iterations As Long = 1000

Public Sub Benchmarks()

    Dim active As Range
    Dim index As Long
    Dim starting As Double
    Dim doc As Document

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    starting = Timer
    For index = 1 To iterations
        Process doc.Content
    Next index
    Debug.Print "Process all: " & Timer - starting & " seconds"

    Dim para As Paragraph
    starting = Timer
    For index = 1 To iterations
        For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
            Process para.Range
        Next para
    Next index
    Debug.Print "Process by paragraph: " & Timer - starting & " seconds"

    Dim sent As Range
    starting = Timer
    For index = 1 To iterations
        For Each sent In doc.Sentences
            Process sent
        Next sent
    Next index
    Debug.Print "Process by sentence: " & Timer - starting & " seconds"

End Sub
```

**"Analysis" Code:**

```
Public Sub Process(target As Range)

    Dim buffer() As String
    Dim pos As Long
    Dim proxy As Long

    buffer = Split(target.Text)
    For pos = LBound(buffer) To UBound(buffer)
        proxy = proxy + InStr(1, buffer(pos), "a")
    Next pos

End Sub
```

**Results:**

```
Process all: 0.75 seconds
Process by paragraph: 2.125 seconds
Process by sentence: 9.078125 seconds
```

I tried to benchmark by word also, but it kept sending the application into "not responding".

Comment: This is great, thanks. How would you go about spliting the document if you were interested in working on sentences as a unit? Not using sentences or paragraphs, that is.

Comment: @RSinohara - It depends on the analysis that you're doing and the content of the document, but byte array scanning for punctuation or regular expressions would be a good start.  Basically ask yourself how you would approach it if it were a plain text document.

Comment: I will and it's great to know the impact of paragraphs and sentences (and that it's huge).
I still need to deal with split ranges as I need to work on revisions of each sentence's range. I'll see what I can do, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Put the analysis into an exe file. You can multitask using multiple exefiles. As your host is an office app (?) this means multiple instances of whichever app.

Remember Lord of the Rings, one process to control them all.

So your main script would send out to other processes instructions to do it in a asych way (the script sets a timer [to do the work] then responds ok and then calls back when finished, poss with an event).